# How can I avoid pixel overlaps on high density Android devices

Tags: android, react-native

I've implemented buttons and other UI elements for React Native using [9-slice scaling technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9-slice_scaling). However, I've stumbled on a problem on Android, which affects some devices - seemingly depending on their pixel ratio or pixel density. What happens is that the views containing the pieces overlap each other. I can't rely on negative margins and such to cover up the gaps as a workaround because I need to support opacity - so that won't work if they overlap each other.

How can I solve this? I've tried all kinds of methods of using React Native's `PixelRatio`, but I'm out of ideas.

I've posted this issue in React Native's Github repo as well (see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34654), but I'm looking for solutions since I don't know when/if that will be resolved.

Below is a simplified reproducible example in Snack, along with a screenshot depicting the problem: https://snack.expo.dev/@insats/346e2f

Here's a more complex snack which uses a 9-slice technique: https://snack.expo.dev/@insats/android-gaps-between-views-flex

[image]